# Implementing complex Processing pushMatrix/popMatrix logic with d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, processing

I want to reimplement the following Processing sketch with d3js.

[Recursion Thing](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/84312)

This wonderful sketch recursively builds up the graph, using a complex pushMatrix, popMatrix hierarchy.

How could this be implemented in d3.js as we there always work on the DOM immediately when appending a shape or transformation. But in a logic like in this sketch the appending part seems to have to be held back for the respective popMatrix to come. It feels like I have to implement my own transform and shape stack to temporary remember the transformation and shapes to be added until the popMatrix comes but that seems so not d3.js.

Any suggestion highly appreciated

ps:
i dont want to use processing.js as i want to work with svg, not canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem! Here's my take on it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y48BL/

This is more a proof of concept; I didn't do all the different colours and such. Nevertheless, it demonstrates the general approach. The general idea is to use `g` elements instead of the matrices that processing uses. Both are used for local transformations of the coordinate system; in the case of the `g` elements by setting `transform` accordingly. New `g`s (matrices) are created inside the recursive function and then passed on to the next level of the recursion. This would correspond to `pushMatrix()`. Coming back up, we continue to use the original `g`, corresponding to `popMatrix()`.

The translation of the drawing of the circles and lines is fairly straightforward -- I find the D3 code much easier to read.

Comment: I would consider svg if there were some evemts associated with the elements. But the 60,000+ svg elements are just eye candy, and would challange browser performance. I'd have to go with canvas for these types of graphics.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer Lars. Nevertheless i am not sure if this approach will do here as we can have more than one pushMatrix/popMatrix call in one recursion step. (you moved the scale into the inner loop by the way) So it seems we need some kind of stack here to store the <g> tags which i am about to implement. Nevertheless  your answer, as usual, already covers the main point, using g elements instead of matrices, so thanks again for your ongoing wonderful support for the d3.js community here.

Comment: Thanks Francis, i completely agree with your performance considerations. Nevertheless I have this long time ongoing svg love and in my concrete application I want to export the graphics and make high quality prints so svg seems the way to go. (canvas can only export to png etc right?)

Comment: By the way Lars, most likely you are aware of it but crispEdges is crap, at least with google chrome on OSX, see https://coderwall.com/p/ufldzw and easy to see in your fiddle. (You might have wanted this effect of course.)

Comment: It's slightly better in other browsers, but you're absolutely right. Like I said, this is really just a proof of concept. Replicating the example exactly would be quite a bit of additional work because of the rendering in processing and D3/SVG works quite differently.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this helper "class" to get this done, maybe a bit of a overkill but I will have more use cases for this.

```
var TransformStack = (function () {
            function TransformStack() {
                this.stack = [];
            }

            TransformStack.prototype.getCurrentElement = function () {
                return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
            };

            TransformStack.prototype.setCurrentElement = function (element) {
                this.stack[this.stack.length - 1] = element;
            };

            TransformStack.prototype.push = function (transformElement) {
                this.stack.push(transformElement);
            };

            TransformStack.prototype.pushAndTransform = function (transformAttr) {
                this.push(this.getCurrentElement().append("g").attr("transform", transformAttr));
            };

            TransformStack.prototype.transform = function (transformAttr) {          
              this.setCurrentElement(this.getCurrentElement().append("g").attr("transform", transformAttr));
            };

            TransformStack.prototype.pop = function () {           
                return this.stack.pop();
            };
            return TransformStack;
        })();
```

Basically a stack to push/pop `g` elements which replaces the matrices approach in processing as Lars already pointed out. With this the main routine looks something like

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
                .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + gScale + ")");

  var tstack = new TransformStack();
  tstack.push(svg);

        doIt(nRecursions);

        function doIt(n) {
// Circle
            tstack.getCurrentElement()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("r", theSize)
                    .style("fill", "#fe6b0c")
                    .style("stroke", "0")
                    .style("stroke-width", "2")
                    .style("opacity", 0.3);

            if (n != nRecursions) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    tstack.getCurrentElement().append("line")
                            .style("stroke", "red")
                            .style("opacity", 0.16)
                            .attr("x1", Math.random() * 4 - 2)
                            .attr("x2", Math.random() * 4 - 2)
                            .attr("y1", theSize / 2.0 + Math.random() * 4 - 2)
                            .attr("y2", distance - (theSize * theScale / 2.0) - 8.0 + Math.random() * 4 - 2);
                }
            }


            var rot = 0;

            tstack.pushAndTransform("scale(" + theScale + ")");

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (n > 0) {
                    tstack.pushAndTransform("translate(0," + distance + ")");
                    doIt(n - 1);
                    tstack.pop();
                    rot = 360 / n;
                    tstack.transform('rotate(' + rot + ')');
                }
            }

            tstack.pop();
        }
    }
```

Just wanted to share this, maybe of some use for some. The main point was given by Lars already.